# How do i navigate between screens in my shopping app?

Tags: react-native

'm new to react-native and mobile application. I'm trying to build a basic shopping app.i have the sports options such as cricket,football,tennis and whenever the cricket button is pressed, the cricket products must be displayed and i can follow it up for the other two products

i tried using stack navigator to navigate between screens but i seem to get a error . i tried using createstacknavigator but it doesnt come out right

1.App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text,  View } from 'react-native';


import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import FirstScreen from './src/FirstScreen'
import SecondScreen from './src/cricket'

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  First: {screen: FirstScreen},
  Second: {screen: SecondScreen}
});

export default Navigation

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Navigation);
```

2.FirstScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, AppRegistry, Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, 
TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, TouchableNativeFeedback, 
TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
export default class FirstScreen extends Component {
//_onPressButton() {
// Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
//}

//_onLongPressButton() {
//Alert.alert('You long-pressed the button!')
//}

  static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'First Screen',
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>

     <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Cricket</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>

     <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Football</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>

     <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Tennis</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
    );
    }
    }   






   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
      paddingTop: 60,
      alignItems: 'center'
      },
   button: {
    marginBottom: 30,
    width: 260,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
     },
  buttonText: {
    padding: 20,
    color: 'white'
    }
    });

    // skip this line if using Create React Native App
    //AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Touchables);
```

3.Cricket.js

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import {Alert, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet, AppRegistry, Text, View 
   } from 'react-native';

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   rowContainer: {
   flex: 1,
   height: 75,
   width: '100%',
   flexDirection: 'row', // children will be on the same line
   justifyContent: 'space-between',
   alignItems: 'center',
   margin: 10,
   },
   buttonContainer: {
   flex: 1,
   },
   text: {
    flex: 2, // Text takes twice more space as button container
   color: 'red',
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   fontSize: 20,
   },
   });


 class Greeting extends Component { 

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Second Screen',
  };

 _onPressButton() {
 Alert.alert('Sorry you have no credit!')
 }

 render() {
   return (
  <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        title="BUY"
      />
    </View>
  </View>
 );

 }
 }

 export default class SecondScreen extends Component {



 render() {
 return (
  <ScrollView>
  <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', top: 0, flex: 2, 
  backgroundColor: 'black'}}>

    <Greeting name='Shoe- 800' />
    <Greeting name='Jersey - 350' />
    <Greeting name='Stockings - 100' />
    <Greeting name='Cones - 50' />
    <Greeting name='Whistle - 80' />
    <Greeting name='Helmet - 750' />
    <Greeting name='Tennis Ball-6 pack - 800' />
    <Greeting name='Nets - 1500' />
    <Greeting name='Leg Pads - 1000' />
    <Greeting name='Stumps - 800' />
    <Greeting name='Gloves - 600' />
  </View>
  </ScrollView>
  );
  }
  }
```

When the cricket button is pressed, the screen should navigate to the list of cricketproducts which is the (cricket.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `react-navigation`, you just need to use the navigation prop. You have commented the part where you handle the press. Just change that function to actually navigate to the screen you want:

```
_onPressButton=()=>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
}
```

If you are not using arrow functions, you need to bind the function to have access to the `this` of that screen. To do that you need to add inside your constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this._onPressButton.bind(this)
}
```

after that you can call it by doing:

```
_onPressButton() {
 this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
}
```

As you are using a stackNavigator, you have different ways to navigate to the other screen of the same stack. You have different ways to navigate. For example:

```
this.props.navigation.push("Second")
```

This method pushes a new screen to the stack, no matter what screen it is

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
```

Navigates to a new screen in the stack, will push it in the stack only if the screen hasn't been focussed before

```
this.props.navigation.replace("Second")
```

This will navigate to a new screen without pushing it to the stack, "replacing" the screen you was watching with the new one.

EDIT.

For the error you stated in the comment, it's because there's not an app container. To do so, just do:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
```

Then do

```
 const Navigation = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  First: {screen: FirstScreen},
  Second: {screen: SecondScreen}
}));
```

Comment: Please look at other answers before posting your own, if you think you can improve on the original answer. Edit it, don't make a new one.

Comment: Edited my question, I already saw that question but tought it didn't explain how to do it and make it work in his code @swonder

Comment: Both answers say pretty much the exact same thing. Like it said, if you can improve on the answer. Edit it, that way it benefits everyone.

Comment: Edited my question with more information and different ways of navigating trough the stack @swonder ^^

Comment: i got the following error - (0, reactNavigation.StackNavigator) is not a function and (0, reactNavigation.StackNavigator) is undefined

Comment: Looking better at the code it looks like you forgot to do createAppContainer, check the edit i made

Comment: it's createStackNavigator not StackNavigator

Comment: Thats what i changed but it reflects the same error

Answer (score 1):

Use the Move Screen command.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
```

Comment: You can also use `this.props.navigation.replace("Second")` to replace the original page with the second, but by doing that you won't get access to `this.props.navigation.goBack()`